# Compile error when using ternary operator with anonymous functions

Tags: c#, ternary-operator

This one's got me flummoxed, so I thought I'd ask here in the hope that a C# guru can explain it to me.

Why does this code generate an error?

```
        Func<IEnumerable<Item>, IEnumerable<Item>, IEqualityComparer<Item>, IEnumerable<Item>> func = strict ?
            (first, second, comparer) => first.Intersect(second, comparer) :
            (first, second, comparer) => first.Union(second, comparer);
```

while this one doesn't:

```
        Func<IEnumerable<Item>, IEnumerable<Item>, IEqualityComparer<Item>, IEnumerable<Item>> func1;
        if (strict)
            func1 = (first, second, comparer) => first.Intersect(second, comparer);
        else
            func1 = (first, second, comparer) => first.Union(second, comparer);
```

Comment: Can you provide the error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C#: No implicit conversion between 'lambda expression' and 'lambda expression'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564935/c-no-implicit-conversion-between-lambda-expression-and-lambda-expression) and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6015747/why-does-funcbool-test-value-f-f-not-compile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lambda arrow `=>` like

```
(first, second, comparer) => first.Intersect(second, comparer)
```

does not possess a type in itself. It is implicitly convertible to all delegate types that match the signature and return type, though. It is also (with some exceptions) convertible to `Expression<Del>` where `Del` is such a delegate.

When you assign the lambda arrow directly to the `func1` variable, the compiler knows exactly what delegate type to convert into. So that works (you second example).

In the first example:

```
strict ?
(first, second, comparer) => first.Intersect(second, comparer) :
(first, second, comparer) => first.Union(second, comparer)
```

(before we even come to the assignment to `func`) the compiler first has to find the best common type of the two types on each side of the colon `:`. But a lambda arrow doesn't have a type, as I said, so that fails. It would work if you said:

```
strict ?
(Func<IEnumerable<Item>, IEnumerable<Item>, IEqualityComparer<Item>, IEnumerable<Item>>)((first, second, comparer) => first.Intersect(second, comparer)) :
(Func<IEnumerable<Item>, IEnumerable<Item>, IEqualityComparer<Item>, IEnumerable<Item>>)((first, second, comparer) => first.Union(second, comparer))
```

but that is ugly, of course. (Actually, you only have to cast *one* of the two lambdas to give it a type, the other one will get the same type automatically then.)

*Addition:*

An analogous thing happens for the `null` keyword which also doesn't have a type by itself but is implicitly convertible to a lot of types (like `string`). So this works:

```
string myString1 = null;
```

while these don't:

```
var myString2 = null;                    // need to cast null to a type, to use var
string myString3 = strict ? null : null; // cast at least one null, to use ternary op
```

Answer (score 1):

it's probably the same cause as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564935/c-no-implicit-conversion-between-lambda-expression-and-lambda-expression)

if you add "func1 = " to your ternary expressions the compile error should disappear