# How to write strongly typed lambda expressions?

Tags: c#, lambda, inline-if

I want to write a lambda expression within an inline if statement. But inline if statement must have strong type results.

```
MyType obj = someObj.IsOk ? null : () => {
   MyType o = new MyType(intVal);
   o.PropertyName = false;
   return o;
};
```

Of course this doesn't work, because lambda expression isn't strongly typed. I thought of using `Func<intVal, MyType>` delegate, to make it strong type.

But how do I use this `Func<>` inside inline if? Is it at all possible of would I have to define my own function outside and use it in inline if statement?

Comment: Well, I don't know what you will do with your saved lambda (use it locally or pass it to some other object/method). If you only use the lambda locally, I guess you should be able to get your job done with the var keyword.

Comment: I've changed my example code. The thing is I have to use constructor with parameters and also set some other property. So object initializer doesn't come into consideration.

Comment: You can use a constructor with parameters and still set properties with an object initializer expression - see my answer for example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even with the more complicated code, you can use an object initializer expression:

```
MyType obj = someObj.IsOk ? null : new MyType(intVal) { ProName = false };
```

If you *really* want to use a lambda though, you could write:

```
MyType obj = someObj.IsOk ? null : ((Func<MyType>) (() => {
   MyType o = new MyType(intVal);
   o.ProName = false;
   return o;
}))();
```

However, this is frankly a *nightmare* of brackets and casts. You can make it simpler with a helper method:

```
public T Execute(Func<T> func)
{
    return func();
}

...

MyType obj = someObj.IsOk ? null : Execute(() => {
   MyType o = new MyType(intVal);
   o.ProName = false;
   return o;
});
```

Answer (score 7):

It has nothing to do with the lambda's typing here. You are trying to return either `null` or (a function taking no arguments and returning a MyType) but you are telling the compiler that the result of that statement is not a function, but just a MyType.  I think what you want to do is

```
MyType obj = someObj.IsOk ? null : new MyType(intVal);
```

Comment: bah, beat me to it :p  I'll delete mine

Comment: check the changed code. I haven't written the correct example. delegate function body is more complicated than just creating a simple object instance. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 2):

If you have something like this ...

```
  var obj = (someObj.IsOK) ? null : () => {
             return new MyType(intVal) { PropName =false }; }
```

You will get the error ...

> "There is no explicit conversion
>   between null and lambda expression."

The reason for that is discussed in this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263151/lambdas-and-the-ternary-operator-weird-issue).

Mark is correct on what you're trying to do with the code sample, except you can set the property in like as well like this ...

```
var obj = someObj.IsOk ? null : new MyType(intVal) { PropName = false };
```