# How can I assign a Func<> using the conditional ternary operator?

Tags: c#, lambda, func

**Update**

In C#10, this syntax is now valid and the compiler will infer a 'natural type' for a lambda [Example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70199481/314291)

**C# 9 and Earlier**

I am aware that `Func<>`s cannot be implicitly typed directly via the `var` keyword, although I was rather hoping that I could do the following assignment of a predicate:

```
Func<Something, bool> filter = (someBooleanExpressionHere)
   ? x => x.SomeProp < 5
   : x => x.SomeProp >= 5;
```

However, I get the error `cannot resolve the symbol, 'SomeProp'`

At the moment, I have resorted to the more cumbersome `if branch` assignment, which doesn't seem as elegant.

```
Func<Something, bool> filter;
if (someBooleanExpressionHere)
{
    filter = x => x.SomeProp < 5;
}
else
{
    filter = x => x.SomeProp >= 5;
}
```

Have I missed something, or will I need to stick with the if-branch assignment?

Comment: Have you tried adding brackets in various places? e.g. `(x => x.SomeProp < 5)`

Comment: The compiler probably doesn't know what type the lambda variable x is.  Why not put the two expressions in separate variables, then assign one of those to the filter variable using the ternary operator?

Comment: @AlexMDC: Did. Doesn't work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
var filter = (someBooleanExpressionHere)
   ? new Func<Something, bool>(x => x.SomeProp < 5)
   : x => x.SomeProp >= 5;
```

Comment: Thank you - and I get to use var - kind of - bonus :) !

Comment: @StuartLC You get to use `var`, but not without *also* explicitly typing out the type name, so you don't actually have the benefit of `var`. Actually, I'd say there's a reasonable number of folks who would consider your original `if`/`else` more elegant than this. (Personally, I'm divided. I have no real preference for one or the other.)

Comment: Yup, hence the 'kind-of'. But at least I don't have to spell out my lambda's signature *twice*!

Comment: To further explain why it needs to be done this way, lambdas in C# don't have a type per-se, the type of a lambda is inferred from the usage.  In the case of the ternary conditional expression, the compiler wasn't able to infer the lambda type since it would need to know that to infer the type of the conditional expression.  Explicitly instantiating a `Func` allows the compiler to figure out the expression type and from there it can infer the type of the other lambda to also be a `Func`.

Answer (score 3):

You should wrap them in a `new Func` since else it cannot convert the one lamdba to the other:

```
 Func<Something, bool> filter = (someBooleanExpressionHere)
   ? new Func<Something, bool>(x => x.SomeProp < 5)
   : x => x.SomeProp >= 5
   ;
```

If you remove the `new Func...` you will get:

> Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'lambda expression' and 'lambda expression'

Comment: The parentheses on the second operand are not strictly necessary, though I agree they are worth adding.  Not everyone remembers all the precedence rules, so it improves readability.

Comment: True, I first tried with two `new Func` but the last wasn't necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly mention the type as the hint to compiler

```
var filter = (condition)
    ? (Func<Something, bool>)(x => x.SomeProp < 5)
   : x => x.SomeProp >= 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

If appropriate, you could assign these selectors to static fields.

```
private static readonly Func<Something, bool> _someFilter = x => x.SomeProp < 5;
private static readonly Func<Something, bool> _someOtherFilter = x => x.SomeProp >= 5;
```

You can then use them later.

```
var filter = (someBooleanExpressionHere) ? _someFilter : _someOtherFilter;
```